# Hive - Checking if an array in each row of a table contains any matching data in a column in another table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have two tables with columns as shown below.

```
Posts:
user STRING,
tag_list ARRAY<STRING>

Tags:
tag STRING
```

Here is some sample data in those tables.

```
Posts:
user1   help, pig
user2   bigdata, hadoop, query, hiveql
user1   hive, hiveql, help

Tags:
hadoop
hiveql
```

If I want to filter out only the rows in Posts table that contain the tags listed in Tags table as shown in the results below, how would I do that in a hive query? I am not sure as to how to join these two tables using array_contains.

```
Expected Query Result:
user2   bigdata, hadoop, query, hiveql
user1   hive, hiveql, help
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get the expected result with this query.

```
select distinct b.user, b.tag_list from 
(select tag from tags) a
join
(select user, tag_list, exp from posts
lateral view explode(tag_list) exploded_table as exp) b
on (a.tag = b.exp);
```